# Unable to add applications to a facebook business page?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook business page - a page which has not facebook user profile associated with it. Now the problem is that I am not able to add any custom application apart from the standard apps provided by facebook (Links, Discussions, Events, Images, Videos) to this page.

I wish to add my application, and static FBML app to this page. I simply dont see the option to do so. Is there something which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can no longer add new static FBML tabs to any Facebook page.

To add an application you need to go to that applications profile page and click on 'Add to my Page' - a pop up will then appear with your page - then click on the respective 'Add to Page' button.

If you're having trouble finding you applications profile page in search the links are of the form:

```
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APP_ID
```

Comment: does not work in  my case. When I go to applications it does not show me the mentioned options.

Comment: Is the profile, that you are logged in with, a listed admin of your fan page?